# Google IMA sdk - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, google-ad-manager, google-ima, google-ads-api

**THE SITUATION:**

In my Vue app I need to show ads using the Google IMA sdk. 
However it seems that the `AdDisplayContainer` it's stuck in an endless update loop.

**JSFIDDLE:**

I have recreated the issue on JsFiddle with a bare minimum example.
You can check the error in the console.

https://jsfiddle.net/fraMussi/53f6vbjh/7/

As you can see there isn't much going on:

- I import the google IMA sdk
- I have basic markup for the video and ad container
- I setup the `adDisplayContainer`
- I have added a watcher to detect the issue

**THE CODE:**

```
this.adDisplayContainer = new google.ima.AdDisplayContainer(
        this.$refs.adContainer, this.videoContent);
```

**THE ERROR:**

It seems that it `adDisplayContainer` gets updated in a loop:

```
Error in nextTick: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" <br>
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

[image]

In a production-like environment I get a similar error message:

```
InternalError: too much recursion
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Do you know why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember the exact solution for this issue. I created a class for googleIma and init the adDisplayContainer in the constructor.